# Master-Detail relationship not cascading on insert in ADO.NET

Tags: ado.net, ironpython

I attempting to handle the insert of a new master record and associated child records in Winforms using IronPython (developing in SharpDevelop 4) against SQL Server, although I think this is a general ADO.NET problem.  The form only ever has one master record (booking) and many detail records (lines). If the master record already exists I can insert child records without issue, but my relationships do not seem to be cascading if a new booking record is added.

Specific code - firstly I add my relationship as follows:

```
parentColumn = self._dataSetBookings.Tables["booking"].Columns["intBookingID"]
childColumn = self._dataSetBookings.Tables["lines"].Columns["intBookingID"]
bookingRelationship = DataRelation("mediabooking",parentColumn,childColumn,True)
self._dataSetBookings.Relations.Add(bookingRelationship)
self._dataSetBookings.EnforceConstraints = True
```

intBookingID is an identity column on the booking table

My apply update procedure looks like this, note the event added on row updated. The sql commands used are effectively 'select * from  where intBookingID = @intBookingID)

```
# update booking
adapter = SqlDataAdapter()
adapter.RowUpdated += self.AdapterUpdateBooking
cmd = adapter.SelectCommand = self.conn.CreateCommand()

cmd.CommandText = self.bookingSqlCmd
parameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@intBookingID", SqlDbType.Int)
parameter.Value = self.BookingID 

builder = System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand()
adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand()
adapter.Update(self._dataSetBookings,"booking")

# update lines
adapter = SqlDataAdapter()
cmd = adapter.SelectCommand = self.conn.CreateCommand()             
cmd.CommandText = self.lineSqlCmd
parameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@intLineBookingID", SqlDbType.Int)
parameter.Value = self.BookingID 

builder = System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand()
adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand()
adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand()      
adapter.Update(self._dataSetBookings,"lines")
```

And finally the RowUpdated event - which only fires once against the booking row so we can obtain the identity of the record just inserted

```
    def AdapterUpdateBooking(self, sender, e):
    cmd = self.conn.CreateCommand()
    #cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()" - this does not work!
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY "
    newBookingID = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

    if newBookingID != System.DBNull:
        for bookingRow in self._dataSetBookings.Tables["booking"].Rows:
            bookingRow["intBookingID"] = newBookingID
```

Tracing this through when the updates are applied the correct ID value is retrieved by the "SELECT @@IDENTITY" call for a new record (but SCOPE_IDENTITY returns null, which I do not understand and may be a clue?). However when the value is applied to the intBookingID field in the Master (booking) table it does not cascade update intBookingID field in the details (lines) table and the insert fails.

However if the Master (booking) record was loaded from the database, and new lines added, the the relationship does work, the intBookingID field correctly set, and the insert succeeds.

I feel I must be missing something trivial, but what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you coded for cascading? I don't see it. Try this.

```
ForeignKeyConstraint oFKey;
oFKey = new ForeignKeyConstraint("BookingForeignkey", parentColumn, childColumn);
oFKey.DeleteRule = Rule.Cascade;
oFKey.UpdateRule = Rule.Cascade;
oFKey.AcceptRejectRule = AcceptRejectRule.Cascade;
self._dataSetBookings.Tables["booking"].Constraints.Add(oFKey);
self._dataSetBookings.EnforceConstraints = True
```

You might want to read this:
[DataTable Constraints (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st1t2c35.aspx)

EDIT: I dont understand this part

```
if newBookingID != System.DBNull:
        for bookingRow in self._dataSetBookings.Tables["booking"].Rows:
            bookingRow["intBookingID"] = newBookingID
```

Why are you assigning all the rows 'newBookingID'? From this I am guessing primary keys might not have been defined for datasets. If they were, the assignment line must have thrown some error.

Comment: Doesn't a foreign key relationship get assigned automatically though when you assign a DataRelation?

Comment: I doubt. A DataRelation is just a simple relation. You can check this out in the Dataset designer. A foreignkey constraint has to be explicitly declared.

Comment: I did, and it does.  Actually I found the problem was a extraneous record insert and nothing to do with this code - but answer accepted because what you say is largely correct.